# What is a pan max stove temperature?

Tags: stove

I often put my stove to maximum for a while with the pan and some oil and whatever meat in it (I wanna specify that the goal of this post is not discussing the why I cook this way and if it's good for recipe).

My question is, can it be bad and damage the pan if the pan is on the stove at max, with oil/butter in it and whatever I cook.

I'm asking because I always assumed, until someone told me, that you can never damage a pan when cooking on stove if it has something in it, disregarding the material and all.

Comment: What type of pan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of pan, how long it is on the heat, and whether or not damage occurs, probably matters here *if there is nothing in the pan*. If the pan has food in it as it is heating, you will almost always burn your food before you could possibly damage your pan.

Comment: thanks!! and my question goes more for like any kind of pan, is your statement true for all kind of pan? and if so, you mean, burn like really burned or even a little black (sorry for my terms I'm french)

Comment: @Cherry. Pans of different material and thickness respond differently.  However, if there is food in the pan while heating, most will ruin your food before you damage the pan.